# How to post select box and not the value of select box

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form, I use the value to generate a dropdown list using ajax. When I post this form to database the value enters into database, but I want the actual name to be entered.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<select name="region">
   <option disabled selected hidden>---Select---</option>
<?php
 $region_sql = "SELECT * FROM `regions`";
 $region_res = mysqli_query($con, $region_sql);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($region_res) > 0){
 while($region_row = mysqli_fetch_array($region_res)){
     echo "<option value='".$region_row[id]."'>".$region_row[region]."</option>";
 } 
}
?>
</select>


<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label for="city">City</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select class="form-control" name="city" id="city" data-live-search="true">
                    <option>First choose a Region</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This array is the issue: `echo "<option value='".$region_row[id]."'>".$region_row[region]."</option>`

It ends up being: `<option value="1">mid atlantic</option>`
value being 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 etc etc..
1 gets entered to the database, but I want mid atlantic to enter in the database.

Is there a way to do this?
thanks!

**Update**

I am using the Id to post it to getstate.php

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#region").change(function()
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
       $.ajax
       ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "getState.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html)
       {
         $("#state").html(html);
       }
        });
            });
  });
```

getstate.php:

```
if($_POST['id']){
    $region_id=$_POST['id'];
    $sql= "select * from states where region_id='$region_id' ORDER BY state ASC";
    $res= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    echo "<option>---Select--</option>";

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['state']."</option>";
        } 
    }else{
        die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
    }
}
```

The code works as is. I just want it to enter the name in the database and not the id number.

Comment: So why not just `value='".$region_row[region]."'` instead of `value='".$region_row[id]."'`?

Comment: As @Xufox mentioned, using `echo "<option value='".$region_row[region]."'>".$region_row[region]."</option>";` should solve your problem.

Comment: I need the id to post that specific row to another page and run a query. updated code.